# pasteHTML removes markup

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, episerver

I am writing a plugin to an old IE-only WYSIWYG-editor which resides in an old CMS. I've created a plugin that opens an popup where the user can enter the url of an youtube clip.

The popup then creates the corrent <object..><param..> markup for the embed and uses Internet Explorers pasteHTML function;

```
var range = plugin.editorDocument.selection.createRange();
var embedHtml = OpenDialog(dialogUrl, null, 400, 200);

if (!embedHtml) {
    return;
}
range.pasteHTML(embedHtml);
```

I know it's missing a bit of information about some of the variables but you get the picture. The problem is that the <param>-tags gets removed when i run the pasteHTML. I wonder if anyone have an idea of fixing this, and letting me keep my param-tags

Comment: What's wrong with using more standard JS, like `innerHTMl`? That should work with nearly every browser around today.

Comment: Because `innerHTML` only exists on elements, not selection objects or TextRanges.

Comment: It's an Iframe based editor.. I've been thinking about using jQuery to manipulate the HTML of the editor. 

That idea took a hold though, when i needed to find out exactly where the object-tag should be placed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest putting an ID on the `<object>` element, getting hold of it after the `pasteHTML` call via `document.getElementById` and using `document.createElement` and the object element's `appendChild` method to create and add `<param>` elements.